# How to divide MNIST training dataset into subparts?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe, mnist

**Background**: I am trying to train different sub-samples of MNIST dataset(1 model for 10,000 , another model for 20,000 samples, and so on until a model for all 60,000 training samples) using Caffe.

**Question**: How do I sub-split the training dataset of 60,000 samples **keeping the format of the training files same(intact) as originally published** on http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just read each line of the file which gives you one data point and write it into an output file. Run a loop for the number of data points you want.